# Django custom static files not collected to s3 bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm configuring my Django project to use S3 buckets to store static and media files, both for local and production settings.

My project tree is as follows:

```
   src/
      blog/
          settings/
                  __init__
                  local.py
                  production.py
          s3utils.py
          [..]
      [..]
```

My `local.py`:

```
access_key = "xx"
secret_key = "yy"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = access_key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = secret_key
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'zz'


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'blog.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'blog.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'us-west-2'
S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + "/static/"
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

import datetime

two_months = datetime.timedelta(days=61)
date_two_months_later = datetime.date.today() + two_months
expires = date_two_months_later.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y 20:00:00 GMT")

AWS_HEADERS = { 
    'Expires': expires,
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=%d' % (int(two_months.total_seconds()), ),
}
```

my `s3utils.py`:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='static') 
MediaRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='media')
```

When I run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

only (django) admin static files are copied to my s3 bucket.

I thought that the problem was that I misconfigured the permission of my IAM user, but actually I do have the permissions to copy the `'admin/'` files to the s3 bucket.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **STATICFILES_DIRS** to your settings.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "/path/to/your/static",
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: Thank you @Rafael, you made my day!